# Assigning an element in a list's value to the value of a corresponding element in another list

Tags: python, python-2.7

python 2

Here is my code:

```
for i in list_current:

    for p in list_previous:

        if p == 5:
            list_current[i] = 5
        else:
            whatever

list_previous = list_current
```

Once p reaches a value of 5, I want it to stay a value of 5 while all other elements continue to simulate. It seems to me that I need the index of my list_current element to be the same as the index of p. "[i]" is incorrect, as it will set all elements of list_current to 5.

I think I should mention that this is my first post. And I did search for this same thing but as I'm also new to python I couldn't adapt other answers to my specific problem, if even applicable.

Thank you.

Edit:
here's the actual code. Undeclared variables are just not included. I doubt it will be of any help which is why I just simplified above.

```
for i in (range(0, cnt)):

    if frame == startframe:
        prevy = [marr[i].off.y]

    for p in prevy:
        if p == yht:
            marr[i].off = c4d.Vector(x, yht, z)
        else:
            marr[i].off = c4d.Vector(x, pstep*yht, z)

    prevy = [marr[i].off.y]
```

Comment: what is `list_current[i]` supposed to be? Also 
`list_previous = list_current ` creates a reference so basically you are iterating over the same list twice

Comment: Could you post example input and output for what you would expect? Most of the time it is not a good idea to manipulate a list you are currently iterating over, [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) are preferred.

Comment: I smell an XY problem... Note that i and p are elements of the lists, not their indices.

Comment: Sorry, I was actually trying to make things more legible by simplifying it. Im working in Cinema 4d so my code has a lot of elements native only to c4d in it. But here it is:

Comment: oops. major noob here. code is in the main post now

Comment: also, list_previous = list_current at the end is so I can store the information at the end of each frame to act as the "previous frame" variable when being considered at the next frame.